# How can I use Javascript to replicate a form partial on-demand?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

**Objective** - Replicate a form section so that multiple entries can be made if required. The form on load will allow x1 (one) entry of details to be made. But if I click 'Add Task' three times the form is replicated on screen 3 times and 4 entries can be made, click twice the form is replicated twice and you can make a 2 additional entries.

**My question** - I am new to javascript and have been following a tutorial and have become unstuck.  My code is not allowing me to acheive the objective. How can I amend code to allow me to replicate form on click

I dont have any visible errors my page just loads but nothing happens

**Additional info** - Not relevant to question but I am building my code on Ruby on Rails

My Form - please see the section between ---- that I want my code to replicate on click

```
    <%= render 'layouts/errors', obj: @category %>
    <p>
      <p>
    <%= simple_form_for(@category) do |f| %>

    <div class='form-group row'>
      <div class='col-sm-8'>
          <%= f.label :name, 'Category : ' %>
      </div>
      <div class="control col-sm-8 mb-4">
        <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'input is-focused form-control', type: 'text', placeholder: 'Job Category Name', autofocus: true  %>
      </div>
    </div>

----this below is the section of my code to replicate --------------------
    <tbody class='fields'>
      <%= f.simple_fields_for :pricings do |builder| %>
      <%= render 'pricing', f: builder %>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
----this above is the section of my code to replicate -------------------

    <div class='form-group row'>
         <div class='col-md-12 mb-4'>
           <%= f.submit class: 'button is-info is-medium is-fullwidth' %>
           <%= link_to_add_row('Add Task', f, :pricings, class: 'btn btn-primary') %>
         </div>
    </div>

    <% end %>



    <div class='col-xs-4 offset-sm-2'>
       [ <%= link_to 'Return to active listings', @listing %> ]
    </div>
```

I have an application helper **link_to_add_row()**

```
  def link_to_add_row(name, f, association, **args)
    new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new
    id = new_object.object_id
    fields = f.simple_fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|
      render(association.to_s.singularize, f: builder)
    end
    link_to(name, '#', class: "add_fields " + args[:class], data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n","")})
  end
```

**Finally my javascript code which exists in assets >> javascripts >> application.js**

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(event) {

  $('form').on('click', '.remove_record', function(event){
    $(this).prev('input[type=hidden]').val('1');
    $(this).closest('tr').hide();
    return event.preventDefault();
  });

  $('form').on('click', '.add_fields', function(event) {
    var regexp, time;
    time = new Date().getTime();
    regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g');
    $('fields').append($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time));
    return event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: You can try my gem https://rubygems.org/gems/vanilla_nested or the gem cocoon, both work pretty similar for that. You seem to be on the right path, it's hard to tell the problem since you see no error.

Comment: If I understand correctly your javascript, it appears that you are appending to the `$('fields')` element a string constant, not html as you might've intended. You need a container element into which to `append` new form fields, and then append html. Suggest you put a breakpoint at the `$('fields')...` line and inspect what you're appending, and where you're appending it. I don't think it's what you intend.